# Operations on Sets. Difference between 2 sets where the elements within are ≥ or ≤ an integer.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am struggling with the following question, first time dealing with sets that state that the elements within are greater/less than and equal to an integer.

Let $R$, $S$ and $T$ be sets defined as follows.

$R = \{x : x \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and either } x \leq −2 \text{ or } x \geq 5\}$

$S = \{−3, −2, 4, 5, 6\}$

$T = \{x : x \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } x \geq 2\}$

Find $R - T$

Can I say that $R - T = \{x : x \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } x ≤ −4 \text{ or } x ≥ 7\}$

Find $(R\cup S) - (R\cap S)$

Can I say that this is equal to $\{x : x \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } x \leq −4 ,\, 4, \text{ and } x \geq 7\}$

I get the feeling that I am way off. I generally draw a venn diagram to get a better understanding of what the question is asking, but in this can I can't :( Please lend a helping hand.

Comment: You may write down the unions and intersections to show us your thinking.

Comment: For $R \setminus T$: NO. Check it with a simple diagram of the real line.

Comment: For R - T, I know that it is asking for every element of R that is not in T. I am assuming R - T would include everything between -∞ to -4 as well as 7 to ∞, but I do not know how I would formally write this answer and if it is right or not. Am i on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of $R\setminus T$ we have

$$R\setminus T = \{x : x \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } x \leq -2\}$$

Because it's the same as $R$ minus all those $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x\geq 2$ (which includes $x \geq 5$)

For $(R\cup S) - (R\cap S)$ what you wrote is OK.

Comment: ahh i just realised I was trying to do R - S instead of R - T, now I see, thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! @JohnLovesMaths